# Update a flag only if ALL matching condition fails

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause, oracle12c

I am trying to write a query in oracle to only update a flag based on below scenario :

**Scenario :**

A mctn_id is linked with multiple PRPR_ID and each PRPR_ID can have different addresses, I need to update flag as N in a table if **ALL** PRPR_ID addresses don't belong to config table address. If any of it belongs to config table address then it shouldn't update the flag as N.

I am using not exists in this case which is not working.

```
update prcb_enroll_tbl
set prov_flg ='N',
sys_insert_dtm = systimestamp
where tin_number in (select mctn_id
                        from cc_pr_prov prpr
                        inner join cc_pr_addr prad
                        on prpr.prpr_id = prad.prad_id
                        and not exists (select 1 
                                        from fsg_prcb_config config
                                        where prad.prad_addr1 = config.config_value)
```

The above query is updating a flag even if only one of the addresses belongs to config table which is not the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoulds like `not exists`. Does this do what you want?

```
update prcb_enroll_tbl pe
set prov_flg ='N', sys_insert_dtm = systimestamp
where not exists (
    select 1
    from cc_pr_prov pr
    inner join cc_pr_addr pa on pr.prpr_id = pz.prad_id
    inner join fsg_prcb_config pc on pc.config_value = pa.prad_addr1 
    where ??.mctn_id = pe.tin_number
)
```

It is unclear which table column `mctn_id` comes from, so I used `???`: you should replace it with the correct table alias.